# How to store an array in the value for Key value pairs of redis server?

Tags: node.js, dictionary, redis, socket.io, key-value

I am using redis server to store key-value(username-socketID) pairs for a chat app in socket.io.

The problem i have faced is that the same username can login from different devices so will have different socketIDs. SO i have to associate an array of socketIDs against one username.
I was trying to associate an array to the key but itseems to be taking only the first element of the array as a string. Below is my code

Setting the array to the key:

```
var socketIDs = [];
            socketIDs.push(socket.id);
            client.set(username, socketIDs, function (err) {
                console.log("IN USERNAME EVENT" + username + ":" + socketIDs);
            });
```

Getting the array from the key:

```
client.get(username, function (err, socketIDs) {
                var i = socketIDs.indexOf(socket.id);
                if (i != -1)
                {
                    socketIDs.splice(i, 1);
                }
                client.set(username, socketIDs, function (err) {
                    console.log(username + " DISCONNECTED");
                    socket.disconnect();
                });
            });
```

When am trying to fetch the value associated with the username, i get just the socketID as a string and not the array format that i had originally added as.

Any fix for this? or what is the best way to approach my requirement of storing multiple values for a single key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a `list` or a `set`. I would use a `list` unless you need duplication checks (if so then use a `set`). All the following examples are `list` based but you can find the equivalents for `set` [here](http://redis.io/commands#set).

**Adding a new socket ID**

```
client.lpush(username, socket.id, function(err) {
    console.log('Prepended new socket ID to list');
});
```

**Getting all socket IDs for a user**

```
client.lrange(username, 0, -1, function(err, socketIds) {
});
```

**Removing a given socket ID**

```
client.lrem(username, socketId, 0, function(err) {
});
```

(I've assumed you're using the [`node_redis`](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) lib).

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed. But there should be a slight change in  the command for removing a given socket id. Edited!

Comment: to remove given socket ID , use client.lrem(username, count, socketId, function(err){}); where count is the number of occurrences to delete. count = 0 to delete all occurrences in list